# How do you decompile a swf file

Tags: flash, decompiling

I am the maintainer of a site that has allegedly 'lost' the source code to a flash swf file.  How do I decompile this source?

Are there any programs online or offline that I could use?

Comment: If you want to convert it to HTML5, you can use Swiffy: http://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/

Comment: Related: [How to decompile an SWF file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2984273/55075)

Answer (score 22):

Usually 'lost' is a euphemism for "We stopped paying the developer and now he wont give us the source code."

That being said, I own a copy of [Burak's ActionScript Viewer](http://www.buraks.com/asv/index.html), and it works pretty well. A simple google search will find you many other SWF decompilers.

Comment: ASV doesn't decompile AS3 / Flash 9 stuff as of yet.

Comment: What are you talkin about, it's decompiled AS3 stuff for ages, I've used it to do such. Of course you have to buy it, the free version is much older than the paid version.

Comment: the link does not seem to work...

Answer (score 11):

erlswf is an opensource project written in erlang for decompiling .swf files.

Here's the site: https://github.com/bef/erlswf

Answer (score 9):

Get the Sothink SWF decompiler. Not free, but worth it. Recently used it to decompile an SWF that I had lost the fla for, and I could completely round-trip swf-fla and back!
[link text](http://www.sothink.com/)

Comment: Sothink is really very good. Lee Brimelow has a nice tutorial on using it: http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play?id=70

Answer (score 2):

I've had good luck with the [SWF::File](http://search.cpan.org/dist/SWF-File/) library on CPAN, and particularly the [dumpswf.plx](http://search.cpan.org/src/YSAS/SWF-File-0.42/dumpswf.plx) tool that comes with that distribution.  It generates Perl code that, when run, regenerates your SWF.

Answer (score 2):

I've used Sothink SWF decompiler a couple of times, the only problem is that as project gets more complex, the output of decompiler gets harder to compile back again. But it ensures that you can get your .as files most of the time, compilable fla is a question.

[Sothink SWF Decompiler](http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/)

Comment: can you add a link to this? I'll upvote then.

Comment: http://download846.mediafire.com/6bvcckso1z1g/kzard29z313rfy3/RABCDAsm.rar  for rabcsm...or https://www.free-decompiler.com/flash/