# How to automatically decompile SWF file on my server?

Tags: flash, decompiling

What language would I need to use?

A bit like http://www.showmycode.com/

And could anyone point me in the right direction to get started?

Comment: are you looking for a library that would do the decompilation for you?  If you are planning on decompiling it yourself, i'dthink that the language doesn'tmuch matter so long as you can directly access the bits in the swf file...

Comment: I was just looking for the most efficient way of doing it.

Comment: efficient by what definition?  efficient for dev time would prolly be to take an existing decompiler and call it from the command line.  Efficient for cost, for ability to sell without licensing restriction, for time to decompile, or for memory usage might require different implementations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you decompile a swf file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97018/how-do-you-decompile-a-swf-file)

Answer (score 5):

- [SWFTools](http://www.swftools.org/) - SWF manipulation and generation utilities

  You can install SWFTools distribution (which has also a command line program), and use [SWFExtract](http://www.swftools.org/swfextract.html), that can decompile flash files.

  On OSX, install via: `brew install swftools`.

  This will install tools such as: `as3compile`, `font2swf`, `jpeg2swf`, `pdf2swf`, `png2swf`,
  `swfbbox`, `swfc`, `swfcombine`,
  `swfdump`, `swfextract`, `swfrender`, `swfstrings`, `wav2swf`.

  `swfextracts` allows to extract swf movieclips and objects out of swf files.

  Example to extract all:

  ```
  swfextract --outputformat "extract_%06d.%s" -a 1- sample.swf
  ```
- [FFDec](https://www.free-decompiler.com/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/jindrapetrik/jpexs-decompiler)) - JPEXS Free Flash Decompiler

  > Opensource flash SWF decompiler and editor. Extract resources, convert SWF to FLA, edit ActionScript, replace images, sounds, texts or fonts. Various output formats available. Works with Java on Windows, Linux or MacOS.

  Examples:

  ```
  java -jar ffdec.jar myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -proxy
  java -jar ffdec.jar -proxy -P1234
  java -jar ffdec.jar -export script "C:\decompiled" myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -selectclass com.example.MyClass,com.example.SecondClass -export script "C:\decompiled" myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -format script:pcode -export script "C:\decompiled" myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -format script:pcode,text:plain -export script,text,image "C:\decompiled" myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -format fla:cs5.5 -export fla "C:\sources\myfile.fla" myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -dumpSWF myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -compress myfile.swf myfiledec.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -decompress myfiledec.swf myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -onerror ignore -export script "C:\decompiled" myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -onerror retry 5 -export script "C:\decompiled" myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -config autoDeobfuscate=1,parallelSpeedUp=0 -export script "C:\decompiled" myfile.swf
  ```

  > Instead of "java -jar ffdec.jar" you can use ffdec.bat on Windows, ffdec.sh on Linux/MacOs

Answer (score 1):

[SWFScan - FREE Flash decompiler](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Following-the-Wh1t3-Rabbit-Down/SWFScan-FREE-Flash-decompiler/ba-p/5440167)

```
THIS is the one, the only, HP's fantastic SWFScan Adobe Flash de-compile tool and
basic 'security scanner' ... use it for the betterment of humanity, and not for 
evil.
```