# Help decompiling SWF!

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs3, flash-cs5

I made a project (into a flash projector for Windows) last year and I lost the source code. I was able to extract the SWF and then decompile it, but for some reason, it won't recompile. I am getting some errors when recompiling.

The original was made in CS3, the new one is being compiled in CS5.

The errors have to do with internal variables in the video classes. What could be the problem?

**EDIT:**

I've gotten this error and other similar ones:

`/Applications/Adobe Flash CS5/Common/Configuration/Component Source/ActionScript 3.0/FLVPlayback/fl/video/UIManager.as, Line 449   1120: Access of undefined property PLAYER.`

**EDIT2:**

It was built in Flash CS3 using AS3 on Windows Vista. I am now on OSX 10.6 and Flash CS5.

**EDIT3:**

If I remember correctly, I had trouble learning to use the FLVPlayback component and I messed with some of the Flash SDK internals back then. Could that be corrupted and included with the SWF?

Also, I've had success with this decompiler in the past. I don't think it's buggy.

(If anyone has a decompiler, I'll gladly let you keep a copy of the source if you can decompile this for me. Just leave a comment.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decompile an SWF file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984273/how-to-decompile-an-swf-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your decompiler is working correctly, it should produce complete source that can be re-compiled successfully (assuming that you don't change the source it produces).  If it's not doing this, then you have a buggy decompiler; you should find a different one.

That said - you may be trying to build it for a later version of the flash runtime than it was intended for.  If you're building it from Flash, you might try going into the project's properties and switching it to target older player version (eg. version 8 or 9).  Also: do you know whether it's AS2 or AS3?  you can try different project settings there too.

If you're still having trouble, then post more detailed info about the errors you're seeing, and I'll do my best to help further.

Comment: Can we move this to the chat.SO site?

Comment: This is no longer top priority, I'm going to rewrite it. That said, I'd still like to get it fixed.