# Decompile .swf, but no code is shown! help please

Tags: flash, decompiling, decompiler

Spent two weeks creating a flash presentation hundreds of photos and the file became corrupted when Nero 7 crashed :( and my pc restarted. A quick seach told me of some decompilers (showmycode.com) could save the file...

but it shows me not one line of code :(

it works fine with other .swf files.

does anyone know why there is not any code shown?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decompile an SWF file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984273/how-to-decompile-an-swf-file)

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for different reasons - outdated decompiler (can't decompile LZMA-compressed SWFs for example), some errors in decompiler, etc.
Try to use other decompilers, like ASV (Action Script Viewer), Sothink or Trillix.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://www.free-decompiler.com/flash/ or rabcsm...also good
 decompilers