# Is there a tool to decompile swf to actionscript?

Tags: flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you decompile a swf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97018/how-do-you-decompile-a-swf-file)

Anyone knows if there's such a tool?

Answer (score 3):

Sothink's decompiler is a good place to start

Answer (score 3):

try [Sothink SWF Decompiler](http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/) , I used it once and its nice

You can even try [Flash Decompiler Trillix](http://www.swf-kit.com/swftofla-decompiler.html)

Answer (score 2):

Sothink's decompiler is good.But you must work hard to understand decompiled source code.

Comment: https://www.free-decompiler.com/flash/