# swf to source code for editing and back to swf

Tags: flash, haxe

I haven't touched code for quite some time and to my knowledge I am dealing with flash and haxe I believe. Is it possible to go from SWF to source code, to edit that code and then back to swf with the revised code? I wanted to take a simple flash game and edit what the character looks like. Also I wanted to remove different modes from the game to keep it simple. To my knowledge the game was originally written in haxe. If anyone could provide some info on this it would be greatly appreciated. thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is too broad, you should ask about more specific problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you decompile a swf file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97018/how-do-you-decompile-a-swf-file)

Comment: Hi Mihail, thanks for the reply! I realized I had to decompile the swf first and got a bit lost afterward as far as editing and recompiling but I think I kind of got it.

Comment: Also, if the swf isn't yours (because, why aren't you working in the source files instead of the output files) you can break copyrights. Because you can decompilate doesn't mean the code/assets are yours/free. You might just want to contact the author of the file.

Comment: oh i got it from a website that stated its open source, I'm not trying to take the game as being mine or anything but i'll let definitely let the website/author know of what im trying to do. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tools available with which you can decompile the SWF file to get the underlying ActionScript 3 source code.

Note, however, that at no point will you deal with Haxe source code. The AS3 code received through decompilation will be the code generated by the Haxe compiler. Sometimes this code includes "shims" for Haxe-specific features that are not native to the target language, but these should be easy to identify and ignore.

Compiling the AS3 back into an SWF does not involve Haxe either. You'll have to find another tool for that, such as the Flex SDK.

Comment: HI Domagoj. Thanks for answering my question and for the advice. After I posted this question I did some more researching and for the most part came to the conclusion of what you posted but I was still unsure. Your answer helps me a great deal because it confirmed what I researched. is it possible for me to get your contact email or something for any future questions? Thanks again for your help!!